# linked list deletion only works for some positions

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am solving the hackerrank questions, and this one question has to do a deletion operation on a linked list.

This is the question:

> Delete the node at a given position in a linked list and return a reference to the head node. The head is at position 0. The list may be empty after you delete the node. In that case, return a null value.

This is the full explanation of the exercise:

> Delete the node at a given position in a linked list and return a reference to the head node. The head is at position 0. The list may be empty after you delete the node. In that case, return a null value.
>
> Example
> 0-> 1 -> 2-> 3
>
> position = 2
>
> After removing the node at position ,2 .
> 0-> 1 -> 3
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the deleteNode function in the editor below.
>
> deleteNode has the following parameters:
>
> - SinglyLinkedListNode pointer llist: a reference to the head node in the list
> - int position: the position of the node to remove
>
> Returns
>
> - SinglyLinkedListNode pointer: a reference to the head of the modified list
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line of input contains an integer , the number of elements in the linked list.
> Each of the next  lines contains an integer, the node data values in order.
> The last line contains an integer, , the position of the node to delete.
>
> Constraints
>
> , where  is the  element of the linked list.
> Sample Input
>
> 8
> 20
> 6
> 2
> 19
> 7
> 4
> 15
> 9
> 3
>
> Sample Output
>
> 20 6 2 7 4 15 9

in simple words, the input will be the total number of linked list elements, followed by the elements, and finally the position where I want to delete the element.

And this is my code:

```cpp
SinglyLinkedListNode* deleteNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* llist, int position) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode* temp;
    SinglyLinkedListNode* head =llist;
    SinglyLinkedListNode* prev = nullptr;
    int i = 0;
    if(position == 0){
        temp = llist->next;
        llist = temp;
        return llist;
    }
    else{
        while(i<position){
            prev = head;
            head = llist->next;
    
            ++i;
        }
        temp = head->next;
        prev->next = temp;
        return llist;
    }
}
```

And this is the full code from the website:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string ltrim(const string &);
string rtrim(const string &);

class SinglyLinkedListNode {
    public:
        int data;
        SinglyLinkedListNode *next;

        SinglyLinkedListNode(int node_data) {
            this->data = node_data;
            this->next = nullptr;
        }
};

class SinglyLinkedList {
    public:
        SinglyLinkedListNode *head;
        SinglyLinkedListNode *tail;

        SinglyLinkedList() {
            this->head = nullptr;
            this->tail = nullptr;
        }

        void insert_node(int node_data) {
            SinglyLinkedListNode* node = new SinglyLinkedListNode(node_data);

            if (!this->head) {
                this->head = node;
            } else {
                this->tail->next = node;
            }

            this->tail = node;
        }
};

void print_singly_linked_list(SinglyLinkedListNode* node, string sep, ofstream& fout) {
    while (node) {
        fout << node->data;

        node = node->next;

        if (node) {
            fout << sep;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Complete the 'deleteNode' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. INTEGER_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST llist
 *  2. INTEGER position
 */

/*
 * For your reference:
 *
 * SinglyLinkedListNode {
 *     int data;
 *     SinglyLinkedListNode* next;
 * };
 *
 */

SinglyLinkedListNode* deleteNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* llist, int position) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode* temp;
    SinglyLinkedListNode* head =llist;
    SinglyLinkedListNode* prev = nullptr;
    int i = 0;
    if(position == 0){
        temp = llist->next;
        llist = temp;
        return llist;
    }
    else{
        while(i<position){
            prev = head;
            head = llist->next;
    
            ++i;
        }
        temp = head->next;
        prev->next = temp;
        return llist;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    SinglyLinkedList* llist = new SinglyLinkedList();

    string llist_count_temp;
    getline(cin, llist_count_temp);

    int llist_count = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(llist_count_temp)));

    for (int i = 0; i < llist_count; i++) {
        string llist_item_temp;
        getline(cin, llist_item_temp);

        int llist_item = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(llist_item_temp)));

        llist->insert_node(llist_item);
    }

    string position_temp;
    getline(cin, position_temp);

    int position = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(position_temp)));

    SinglyLinkedListNode* llist1 = deleteNode(llist->head, position);

    print_singly_linked_list(llist1, " ", fout);
    fout << "\n";

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}

string ltrim(const string &str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(
        s.begin(),
        find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace)))
    );

    return s;
}

string rtrim(const string &str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(
        find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))).base(),
        s.end()
    );

    return s;
}
```

For some reason, this code only works for the position value 0 and 1, and does not work for any other value.

Comment: `prev = head; head = llist->next;` Your loop just repeatedly assigns the same values to the same variables. It doesn't actually walk forward in the list, no matter how large `position` is.

Comment: There's a popular myth about a secret shortcut to becoming an elite C++ guru: throw away your C++ textbooks; instead do random coding puzzles that, otherwise, have no inherent learning value, they don't teach anything except bad programming habits. This myth comes from many clickbait web sites, like HackerRank, that promise that doing their puzzles turns anyone into an instant C++ uberhacker. Everyone eventually realizes how useless these coding puzzles are, but only after wasting a massive amount of time doing one coding puzzle after another. And they have nothing to show for it.

Comment: You will be better of learning more about C++ and the standard library first. There usually is no need to write your own datastructures (like lists) to solve problems on competitive coding sites. Those sides should not be used to learn C++, only to have fun and training your problem solving skills. The code quality of the examples is poor, and usually contain tricks that only make the code worse (while claiming they improve performance)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It seems to give the correct output for the input shown in the prompt. The `if (prev)`  and `if (temp != head)` fix some segfaults I experienced while testing the code, where position was either greater than the number of nodes in the list or negative.

The rest of the code in the question has a few memory leaks. There are a couple of calls to `new` but no `delete` calls. To avoid memory leaks, smart pointers (`unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr`/`scoped_ptr`(Boost)) can be used instead of new/delete.

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* deleteNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* llist, int position) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode* temp;
    SinglyLinkedListNode* head =llist;
    SinglyLinkedListNode* prev = nullptr;
    int i = 0;
    if(position == 0){
        temp = llist->next;
        delete llist;
        llist = temp;
        return llist;
    }
    else{
        temp = head;
        while (temp && i<position) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
    
            ++i;
        }
        if (prev)
            prev->next = temp ? temp->next : nullptr;
        if (temp != head)
            delete temp;
        return head;
    }
}
```